# order of evaluation defining a function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I'm quite sure this is an easy question but Im missing something.

I wish to define a function whose action depends on whether the input is a single  matrix or a multiplication of two, For example:

I would want to do get:

```
f[x*y]
(* x+y *)

f[x]
(* x *)
```

Even though this example isn't interesting it is enough to demonstrate my issue.

I tried:

```
f[x_] := If[Head[Unevaluated[x]] == Times, 
(Unevaluated[x][[1]]) + (Unevaluated[x][[2]])
,
x]
```

Indeed I get:

```
f[x*y]==x+y
(* True*)
```

But I get:

```
f[x]
(* If[Symbol == Times, Unevaluated[x][[1]] + Unevaluated[x][[2]], x] *)
f[7]
(* If[Integer == Times, Unevaluated[7][[1]] + Unevaluated[7][[2]], 7] *)
```

Any explanation or an explanation of a better way to achieve my goal are welcome

Comment: See `HoldAll` and friends.

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]`?

Comment: This doesn't help, tried it. Apparently the problem lies with the comparison `Symbol==Times`, and `Integer==Times` which for some reason doesn't evaluate to `False`.

Comment: You should use [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (or `===` for short) when comparing e.g. Heads. This ensures that the comparison is always evaluated to `True` or `False`, and not left unevaluated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Note

This answer explains why the problem in the question happens and how to solve it without changing the approach. [Alucard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154289/36508) shows how to solve the problem with a more "Mathematica like" approach using `SetDelayed` with different patterns.

#### Original answer

A bit of an explanation of what I already said in the comments:

If you look at the output for `f[x]`, you'll see that `Symbol == Times` has not been replaced by `False`. For this reason, the `If` expression is returned unevaluated.

This happens because `Symbol` and`Times` don't have a value (although they are "known" symbols, they're treated as unknown variables for the sake of comparison since there are no `OwnValues`).

To always get either `True` or `False`, you can use [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (`===` for short):

```
In[1]:=  Symbol === Times
Out[1]:= False
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use pattern matching

```
f[x_*y_] := x+y
f[x_] := x
```

examples:

```
f[2*3]
f[x]
f[x*y]
f[5]
```

gives you

```
 5
 x
x + y
 5
```